# Launch event of a key without press any key

Tags: java, android

I want launch the event of a key (back p.e) but without press any key. I saw functions like `onKeyDown` or `onKey`, but for these functions I need a corresponding key event.

Also I try to initialise an `KeyEvent` like here:

```
KeyEvent telo = new KeyEvent(0,0,0,4,0,0,0,158,72);
onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, telo);
```

but it is not working, maybe because I don't know the values of `downTime`, `eventTime` and `deviceId`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you want the behavior of a key, just do whatever the key was supposed to do. If you are trying to affect other applications with these fake events, that is not possible for an app to do, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: There was a bug that permitted you to lure the user into doing this some time ago, but it's since been patched.  If you do find out how to drive third party applications please file a bug report as this type of action would be considered a security defect.

Comment: The finality of this app is that the user can (with help of opencv library and the frontal camara) surf the menus of them device. So, if the camara detect one move for the rigth, i will launch the event of the right key. do you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do this for testing purposes. The [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) API allows you to send key events to your own activities.

specifically:

```
Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

seems like what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

This snippet sends a back key event to the active window. Note that the `sendKeyDownUpSync()` method cannot be called from the main thread.

```
final Instrumentation i = new Instrumentation();
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      i.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: thanks but produces this error:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendKeyDownUpSync(int) from the type Instrumentation

Comment: It's not a static method... you need to get an instance of the Instrumentation object.

Comment: @user2087826 you need to create an Instrumentation object with its constructor and call the method on your instance. Diving in to Android development before you've got the basics of Java syntax down is going to be incredibly difficult. I strongly suggest you go back and brush up on your Java fundamentals before you attempt to create this project.